# How to orient a 3D object in relation to its direction and the ground?

Tags: math, 3d, three.js

[image]

In my game I have characters walking around a 3d terrain. The characters treat the terrain however as a 2d game map, so each character has a direction and a rotation on a 2d plane.

I want to rotate the characters as they're walking on the terrain, so that they are oriented to stand in relation to the terrain, rather then always be oriented as if they're walking on flat ground. This with keeping the original direction of the characters.

**Basically I want**

[image]

For each arbitrary x\z (width\depth) point on the game map I have

1. the (x,y,z) vector of the point on the terrain
2. The normal of the the specific terrain face related to the point

Using this, how do I set the rotation of the characters to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which axis you would like to rotate the object the dot product of the faces normal with that axis will return you the cosine of the angle between the two vectors. By that angle you would have to rotate your object.